# Angular4 refresh page repeats page in url

Tags: angular, routes

I'm an Angular newb and build a simple one pager. I have the router setup so that the empty url redirects to Dashboard component. Hence `localhost:4200` will automatically route to `localhost:4200/dashboard`  Perfect.

However, if I click the refresh button then it appends another dashboard to the url, and oddly enough the page actually loads fine.
`localhost:4200/dashboard/dashboard`

If I hit refresh again it adds a another dashboard to the url and now it won't load

```
localhost:4200/dashboard/dashboard/dashboard
```

The question being, why does it keep adding '/dashboard' to my url on every page refresh?

Here is routing.module.ts

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DashboardComponent } from '../_feature/iacuc/dashboard.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }

    // otherwise redirect to home
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

export const Routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" >
    <title>Angular 2 JWT Authentication Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- bootstrap css -->
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- application css -->
    <link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

The rest of the code is boilerplate you see in the introductory examples, but I can show more code if it's helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: `pathMatch: 'prefix'` change to `pathMatch: 'full'`

Comment: The keyword is literally 'prefix' haha

Comment: 'full' doesn't work either.

Comment: if you do not have base href at the top of your `head` section in `index.html`, than try to add it as: `<base href="/">` (https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href)

Comment: I have that in there too. I updated my question to show my index.html. I think I might just download the Angular.io hero application and swap out their pages with mine instead of doing it from scratch and trying to find this arcane bug in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use **`pathMatch: 'full'`** instead of **`pathMatch: 'prefix'`**

read here: https://angular.io/api/router/Routes

Comment: In addition to changing it to pathMatch: 'full' as you suggested, also need to change the route from using a string to using the component name. It is appending that string to the root url. Correct route:     { path: '', component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }

Comment: I tried to add pathMatch: 'full', but still getting same issue, its adding same page name in URL on reload of page. Any other solution to this ?, i am getting this issue after generating build using command `ng build --prod --aot --base-href;`