# Angular 6 repeats page in url and child routes are not working

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

When I refresh page the page adds `http://localhost:4200/login` -> `http://localhost:4200/login/login`

and when I add direct path to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` It should redirect to its child route but it is redirecting to `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/login` instead.

I have angular structure like this

I have created layout component where I output router `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` parent components
i.e login,request-access,dashboard

and in dashboard i included another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for the child paths of the router

My Routes for this structure are as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'request-access',component:RequestAccessComponent},
  {path:'dashboard',component:NavigationComponent,
    children:[
      {path:'',redirectTo:'admin',pathMatch:'full'},
      {path:'admin',component:AdminLandingComponent},
      {path:'user-list',component:UserListComponent},
      {path:'new-request',component:NewRequestComponent},
      {path:'payments',component:PaymentsComponent}
    ]
  }
];
```

this problem occurred when I added this code in `login.component.ts` to redirect to the dashboard. after removing code having same issue

```
loginUser(username:string,password:string){
    console.log(username,password);
    if(username ===""){
      this.erroMessage = "Please enter username."
    }else if(password === ""){
      this.erroMessage = "Please enter password."
    }else{
      if(username === "admin" && password === "admin"){
        localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn',"true");
        localStorage.setItem('name',"admin");
        this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
      }else{
        this.erroMessage = "Wrong username password. Please try again later"
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried clearing the local storage using `localStorage.clear();`
 but still the problem occurs

refer this image if I am doing something wrong in the folder structure
[image]

I have referred to this question and angularjs documentation
[Angular4 refresh page repeats page in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823738/angular4-refresh-page-repeats-page-in-url)

Comment: Try to remove `{path:'',redirectTo:'admin',pathMatch:'full'}` from children array

Comment: are you using two module for routing?

Comment: yes one in layout.component.html and another in navigation.component.html(dashboard) and removing `{path:'',redirectTo:'admin',pathMatch:'full'}` does not work

Comment: Share the both module `ROUTES`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sorry, I am using only one module `ROUTES` but using two `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` for same module

Comment: add `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' }`

Comment: How are you activating the routes? Are you using a `routerLink`? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/parikshitparab6477/travel/get/749df89c35b9.zip

Comment: @DeborahK  `<li><a routerLink="/dashboard/user-list">List of Users</a></li>`

Comment: Consider turning on route tracing to view in the console what the router is doing. You can turn it on with `enableTracing: true` in the route configuration. Example here: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: @DeborahK Thankyou for the tip. It helped to check what was wrong. I added `<base href="/">` this instead of `<base href="">` this in index.html and it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using two module to define the `ROUTES`, just try to change:

In app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      // other ROUTES
      { path: '**', component: Your_page_not_found_component}
])
```

In app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In login component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}
```

After successful login in that method:

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

Comment: I tried this it is not working bitbucket.org/parikshitparab6477/travel/get/749df89c35b9.zip  this is my code